# IIS .net core with .net 4.5 sub apps

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, asp.net-core, iis-8

We have a collection of .net 4.5 applications that sit under IIS as follows:

```
example.com (IIS Parent App)
    /MyForm (IIS Sub Application)
    /MySecureArea (IIS Sub Application)
```

We have rewritten the parent app (www.example.com) to utilise .net Core. When we try to deploy to IIS we are having issues.

The parent app responds to requests successfully. The sub app /myform successfully responds to requests. However requests for the assets (js/css/images) return a HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Sample URLs and response codes:

```
example.com 200 OK
example.com/css/site.css 200 OK
example.com/myform 200 OK
example.com/myform/css/main.css 502.5 Process Failure
```

The error suggests the .net core app is trying and failing to handle the request. Advice please?

Comment: Do you have routing tables in parent app?

Comment: We didnt in the .net4.5 incarnation. Do we need them now?

Comment: Have you set up any static file middleware?

Comment: Did you figure out the problem?

Comment: No. Our workaround was to have another copy of the site running under a separate IIS website. We used this to serve the assets from myform.example.com sub domain